# Selecting the last N characters before caret with AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey, caret

Is there a way to select last *N* symbols with autohotkey?

I'm making a function which replicates Sublime Text's duplicate function (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>). I want text to be selected before it is duplicated via `SendInput ^C{right}^V`

Technically, I could make something like:

```
selectBefore(n){
    Loop, %n% {
        SendInput +{Left}
    }
}
```

But that has shown poor performance.

Another method would be to play with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>. For example, `Send +{Home}`, then count the number of symbols selected, then `Send {Left}` and `Send +{Home}` again, and so on until reaching the length of the duplicated string.

I don't see any better alternatives.

Is there a good, basic way to select *N* symbols before caret?

Answer (score 3):

From what I read about ST2 (thank you for making me aware) is that ^+d either copies the selected text or if nothing is selected, copies the whole line.

Would this work?

```
TempCB = %ClipBoard% ; Park clipboard (text) content, Other content (format, images, etc.) will be lost.
ClipBoard = ; Clear clipboard
Send, ^c ; Grab selected text
Sleep, 100 ; Wait 0.1 seconds for clipboard (clipboard will not get filled if nothing is selected)
if (Clipboard = "") ; Nothing selected, thus copy whole line
{
    Send, {Home}+{End}^c ; Select line and copy to clipbard
}
MoveBack := StrLen(ClipBoard)
MoveFwd := MoveBack
MoveBack++ ; Move one step back further back due to earlier step {right}
Send, {Right}{Left}^v{Right}{left %Moveback%}+{Right %MoveFwd%} ; Go to end of selected text (in MS notepad this is will jump over the first next char., thus a jump back as well), add a space and paste.
ClipBoard = %TempCB% ; Restore (text part) of previous clipboard content.
Return
```

I tested this in MS Notepad, other editors might behave differently (especially around jumping towards the end of the selected text).
The script now copies and pastes the selected text and highlights the newly pasted text.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! But actually, ST2 `Ctrl + Shift + D` not just copies, but duplicates selected text. That means it is copied at first, then it's pasted, and then pasted text has been selected. So, first and second task are easy to be managed, but selecting of pasted text isn't as easy as it seems like… That's main trouble.

Comment: Dmitry, Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Yeah, thanks. But actually it makes selection almost the same way as my method with `Loop`: it's too slow on big texts being duplicated (300 characters and more). So I wonder if there another way to select inserted text, other than `Send +{Right %N%}`